# Why do permission errors doom a transaction with XACT_ABORT set to OFF and ANSI_WARNINGS set to ON?

Tags: sql-server, error-handling

Consider the following T-SQL in which the user doesn't have permission to execute `SP_TRACE_GENERATEEVENT`:

```
SET XACT_ABORT OFF;

SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON;

BEGIN TRANSACTION;

BEGIN TRY
    EXEC SP_TRACE_GENERATEEVENT;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
END CATCH;

COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

I don't expect to get an error per the [documentation for `SET XACT_ABORT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-xact-abort-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#remarks):

> When ANSI_WARNINGS=OFF, permissions violations cause transactions to abort.

However, I receive the following error as shown in the [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=8597383ac3cb4671028a5bf4977e2981):

> Msg 3930 Level 16 State 1 Line 11
> The current transaction cannot be committed and cannot support operations that write to the log file. Roll back the transaction.
>
> Msg 3998 Level 16 State 1 Line 1
> Uncommittable transaction is detected at the end of the batch. The transaction is rolled back.

This issue can happen with other types of security issues besides calling SP_TRACE_GENERATEEVENT. For example, I've seen it when trying to query a table in which the user cannot connect to that database. I don't have a complete list of error cases.

Why does a permission error doom the transaction with `XACT_ABORT` set to `OFF` and `ANSI_WARNINGS` set to `ON`?

Answer (score 3):

SP_TRACE_GENERATEEVENT is an Extended Stored Procedure

```
SELECT so.name, so.type_desc
FROM sys.system_objects AS so
WHERE so.name = N'SP_TRACE_GENERATEEVENT'
```

[image: screenshot of query results in SSMS showing SP_TRACE_GENERATEEVENT is an extended stored procedure]

Those work in a different way as per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/extended-stored-procedures-programming/how-extended-stored-procedures-work?view=sql-server-ver16)

> The process by which an extended stored procedure works is:
>
> When a client executes an extended stored procedure, the request is
> transmitted in tabular data stream (TDS) or Simple Object Access
> Protocol (SOAP) format from the client application to Microsoft SQL
> Server.
>
> SQL Server searches for the DLL associated with the extended stored
> procedure, and loads the DLL if it is not already loaded.
>
> SQL Server calls the requested extended stored procedure (implemented
> as a function inside the DLL).
>
> The extended stored procedure passes result sets and return parameters
> back to the server by through the Extended Stored Procedure API.

Here's an [Erland Sommarskog article](https://www.sommarskog.se/error_handling/Part2.html#XPs) about error handling in Extended Stored Procedures

> SQL Server still ships with quite a few extended stored procedures,
> whereof some are documented and others are only intended for the tools
> that ship with SQL Server. With regards to error handling, all bets
> are off with these guys. There is no consistent behaviour, and about
> every XP has its own twist. Here is a brief exposé.
>
> The most popular XP is certainly xp_cmdshell. If an error occurs when
> running the operating-system command, this does not raise an error in
> T‑SQL, but you can check the return code from xp_cmdshell or trap the
> output in a one-column table with INSERT-EXEC.

And this related SO question: [SQL Server catch error from extended stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2017212/sql-server-catch-error-from-extended-stored-procedure)

Comment: I get the same error when selecting from a table.

Comment: Can you repro? When I try with missing table permissions, I don't get a doomed transaction.

Comment: This is the error that causes the doomed transaction: Msg 916, Level 14, State 2, Line 50
The server principal "test_perms" is not able to access the database "GFM_Training" under the current security context.

Comment: That sounds like a Cross Database access. Hard to say without a repro script.